# i want to get name of files and shows them on o list,but there are errors

Tags: android, listview, sftp, jsch

i want to get name of files and shows them on o list,but there are errors

```
 ls=sftpChannel.ls("/home/volkan/");

                     l.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter() {

                         public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                                ViewGroup parent) {
                             view= new TextView(parent.getContext());

                             l.post(new Runnable() {
                                 public void run() {
                                     for(int i=0;i<ls.size();i++){
                                            view.setText(((LsEntry)ls.get(i)).getFilename());
                                            return;}
                                 }
                             });
                            return null;
                        }
                        public int getCount() {
                             return ls.size();
                        }

                        public Object getItem(int position) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            return null;
                        }

                        public long getItemId(int position) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            return 0;
                        }



                     });
```

11-06 15:45:00.955: E/AndroidRuntime(18820): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1344
11-06 15:45:00.955: E/AndroidRuntime(18820): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
11-06 15:45:00.955: E/AndroidRuntime(18820):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4267)
11-06 15:45:00.955: E/AndroidRuntime(18820):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChild(ViewRootImpl.java:855)
11-06 15:45:00.955: E/AndroidRuntime(18820):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:904)
11-06 15:45:00.955: E/AndroidRuntime(18820):    at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4005)
11-06 15:45:00.955: E/AndroidRuntime(18820):    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:8716)
11-06 15:45:00.955: E/AndroidRuntime(18820):    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:8667)
11-06 15:45:00.955: E/AndroidRuntime(18820):    at android.widget.AbsListView.resetList(AbsListView.java:1828)
11-06 15:45:00.955: E/AndroidRuntime(18820):    at android.widget.ListView.resetList(ListView.java:502)
11-06 15:45:00.955: E/AndroidRuntime(18820):    at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:442)
11-06 15:45:00.955: E/AndroidRuntime(18820):    at com.example.Bitirme18.Bitirme18Activity$lsnr$1.run(Bitirme18Activity.java:165)
11-06 15:45:00.955: E/AndroidRuntime(18820):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

Comment: yes? and? the error clearly states what the problem is.

Comment: "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views".  Just google for that error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't update the UI from different thread. I had updated your code. Check it..

```
 ls=sftpChannel.ls("/home/volkan/");

l.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter() {

public View getView(int position, View convertView,
       ViewGroup parent) {
    view= new TextView(parent.getContext());  
    view.setText(((LsEntry)ls.get(position)).getFilename());
    return view;
}
public int getCount() {
    return ls.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return 0;
}

});
```

Comment: there is a "i" i is counter for a loop.where is the loop at this code ?

Comment: i add loop but there are errors:11-06 16:22:18.296: E/AndroidRuntime(20164): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1458
11-06 16:22:18.296: E/AndroidRuntime(20164): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
11-06 16:22:18.296: E/AndroidRuntime(20164):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4267)
11-06 16:22:18.296: E/AndroidRuntime(20164):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChild(ViewRootImpl.java:855)

Comment: write `position` inplace of `i`

Comment: `ls=sftpChannel.ls("/home/volkan/");

               l.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter() {

               public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                      ViewGroup parent) {
                   view= new TextView(parent.getContext());
                   for(int i=0;i<ls.size();i++){
                   view.setText(((LsEntry)ls.get(i)).getFilename());}
                   return view;
               }`

Answer (score 0):

Where are you calling this section of code from? According to the error message, you are using something different than the UI thread. This causes your problem...

The Adapter implementation is also broken, getView should return the view referred to by the position parameter.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View view = new TextView(parent.getContext());
    l.post(new Runnable() {
        view.setText(((LsEntry)ls.get(position)).getFilename());
    });
    return view;
}
```

but this is still ugly, as you should cache filenames already resolved... A better approach could be imho, to do the filename mapping in a separate thread, and if you have that result, then set the adapter. That would considerably simplify your job...

Comment: error :Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on tokens, AnnotationName expected instead
 - Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete 
  EnumHeaderName
 - Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete 
  ClassBodyDeclarations

Comment: Well, if you really want to learn how to do this, I'd advise taking simple J2SE lessons, and then reading either the official android dev site, or [the book by commonsware](http://commonsware.com/Android/)